# jQuery, HTML, how to get the number of days between two dates and post it

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

For my datepicker I have jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery-ui-1.10.4.js, and I'm trying to simply put the amount of days between datepicker1 and datepicker2 in a box next to it.

on my page in wordpress I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: "MM d, yy" });
});
</script><script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: "MM d, yy" });
});
</script>
```

and the user can just change the dates:

```
<strong>Date</strong> 
<input id="datepicker1" type="text" name="datepicker1" value="" /> - 
<input id="datepicker2" type="text" name="datepicker2" value="" /> 
<input id="calculated" type="text" name="calculated" value="" /> Day(s)
```

What do I do so when the user changes dates it shows the difference in "calculated"? Note I am a novice at javascript, and I've been searching around but nothing helps me.

Comment: the moment.js library is excellent for things like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`getDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) to fetch Date objects from datepicker and then find out the difference like this:

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: "MM d, yy" });
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: "MM d, yy" });

    $('#datepicker2').on('keyup mouseup change', function(){
        var date1 = $('#datepicker1').datepicker( "getDate" );
        var date2 =  $('#datepicker2').datepicker( "getDate" );
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        var diff = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

         $('#calculated').val(diff);
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<strong>Date</strong> 
<input id="datepicker1" type="text" name="datepicker1" value="" /> - 
<input id="datepicker2" type="text" name="datepicker2" value="" /> 

<br><br>

<input id="calculated" type="text" name="calculated" value="" /> Day(s)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SJN93/1/)

Comment: how do I put this into my HTML <input id="calculated" type="text" name="calculated" value="" />

Comment: I put all this between an <script type="text/javascript"> tag, but still did nothing. How do I put it in my page?

Comment: I tried this and when I hit submit it does nothing ... I would also like it without the submit button, so it shows automatically the difference

Comment: I tried it again on my website and doesn't work, why doesn't this work on my website? do I need to downgrade to jQuery UI 1.9.2 and jQuery 1.9.1?

Comment: **This will work** : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> `

Comment: ok the problem was wordpress needed to add // <![CDATA[ // ]]> into the scripts, now it works, but how can I use this without a submit button?

Comment: thanks, i was busting my head over this all day ... wordpress was also  changing things

Answer (score 0):

you get the difference in days like so:

```
function dateDiffDays(d1, d2) {
    var t2 = d2.getTime();
    var t1 = d1.getTime();
    return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000));
}

var date1 = $("#datepicker1").datepicker("getDate");
var date2 = $("#datepicker2").datepicker("getDate");

var dateDiffInDays = dateDiffDays(date1, date2);
```

to put the value into the "calculated" input field:

```
$('#calculated').val(dateDiffInDays);
```

Comment: ok but how do I put this into my HTML <input id="calculated" type="text" name="calculated" value="" />

Comment: $('#calculated').val(dateDiffInDays);

Comment: how do I add all this into my page? I put your code in between <script type="text/javascript">, but still it did not show the amount of days

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it, this is assumming DateTime is formatted DD/MM/YYYY

```
        var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
        var endDate = $("#endDate").val();

        var startDateSplit = startDate.split("/");
        var endDateSplit = endDate.split("/");

        var stDate = new Date(startDateSplit[2], (startDateSplit[0] - (1)), startDateSplit[1]);
        var enDate = new Date(endDateSplit[2], (endDateSplit[0] - (1)), endDateSplit[1]);

        var daysBetween = (enDate.getTime() - (stDate.getTime())) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); // time in days
```